# android application only triggered to event which sent from debug console pusher

Tags: android, pusher

I am building an android chat application and back-end developer used pusher to build POST API.
When I test API from Post man or via my application it send an event correctly into pusher debug console.
but my application didn't trigger for this event.
and also when I send a manual event from debug console of pusher application triggered for it and display it.

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private APIService service;
    private final String TAG = "API Message";
    private Pusher pusher;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());


        PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions();
        options.setCluster("eu");

        Pusher pusher = new Pusher(xxxxxxxxx, options);

        pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
                Log.i("Pusher", "State changed from " + change.getPreviousState() +
                        " to " + change.getCurrentState());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem connecting! " +
                        "\ncode: " + code +
                        "\nmessage: " + message +
                        "\nException: " + e
                );
            }
        }, ConnectionState.ALL);

        Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("chat");

        channel.bind("MessageSent", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PusherEvent event) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Received event with data: " + event.getData());
            }
        });

        binding.button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            sendMessage();
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        pusher.disconnect();
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        MessageBody body = new MessageBody(userID, msg);

        initializeRetrofit();

        service.sendMessage(helper.getToken() , body)
                .enqueue(new Callback<MessageResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<MessageResponse> call, Response<MessageResponse> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            MessageResponse message = response.body();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message.getChat()
                                    .getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<MessageResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", t);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initializeRetrofit() {
        service = RetrofitClient.getClient("https://mychatapi/")
                .create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

so what is the problem with my code to trigger messages sent from post man or my application ?